# Last_user_update column in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats table in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQlserver, which has 1000 records 10 days ago. So, after 10 days when i checked the record count it is 2000 (not bothered about who is inserting records). when i query in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats table to get last_user_update, there are no records available for my table even though the record has increased to 2000 from 1000. I've even checked in sys.dm_os_sys_info for sqlserver restart time and last restart was a month ago.

What could be the reason for absense of records in index_usage_stats and if record count is getting increased it should be captured in last_user_update column, am i missing something? Pls suggest.

Comment: "The counters are initialized to empty whenever the database engine is started. Use the sqlserver_start_time column in sys.dm_os_sys_info to find the last database engine startup time. **In addition, whenever a database is detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are removed.**" Was there a restore performed on that database in the last 10 days or was it set to offline? Was there memory pressure on that server?

Comment: Hi @Pred, yes i have already checked server restart time and the server has been restarted last month. The database is online and i dont understand why there is no record available for my table in index_usage_stats, especially in last_user_update column.